# AWS SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am new to both php and aws and I have come across an issue trying to link the aws to the simple-login php script.

(https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal).

I'm getting the following error printed:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

This is my code

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    //set timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    //database credentials
    define('DBHOST','instancename.cfci0i1rm4rl.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com');
    define('DBUSER','name_root');
    define('DBPASS','rootpassword');
    define('DBNAME','login');

    //application address
    define('DIR','https://union.washmel.com/user/login/auth/lr/');
    define('SITEEMAIL','noreply@domain.com');

    try {

        //create PDO connection
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
        //$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);//Suggested to uncomment on production websites
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);//Suggested to comment on production websites
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        //show error
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        exit;
    }

    //include the user class, pass in the database connection
    include('classes/user.php');
    include('classes/phpmailer/mail.php');
    $user = new User($db);
?>
```

as follows is the link to the error on my site as it currently stands. 
https://union.washmel.com/user/login/auth/lr/index

Comment: My guess is that your IP has not been given access via the RDS security group.  Have you checked that?

Comment: I should check the DBHOST. Should it really be such a long Server url?

Comment: @RodrigoM I added my server's IP and whitelisted it. I hope I did it right. Still doesn't work... I whitelisted my ip with the following parameters: Type: MYSQL Protocol: TCP Port Range: 3306 Custom IP: 198.55.147.48/32 (The IP was changed)

Comment: Is the instance on a public subnet?

Comment: Check the mysql server is running or not and also check the mysql log files. These are basic steps to begin to resolve this. If both are running well try to check the hard disk space also :)

Comment: I just clone the source and added it into xampp with mac host and its working well

Comment: try to set the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 in my.cnf and restart mysql. MySQL by default refuses all connections that do not come from localhost.